# Jasmine, JQuery UI addClass Test Problem

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, automated-tests, jasmine

I'm trying to test the simplest case of addClass with a duration (using jQuery UI and Jasmine).

Here's the test that's failing:

```
it("should use jquery ui", function() {
  runs(function() {
    expect(el.hasClass("fdsa")).toBeFalsy();
    el.addClass("fdsa", 1000);
    expect(el.hasClass("fdsa")).toBeFalsy();// this should not be failing, but it is
  });

  waits(1000);

  runs(function() {
    expect(el.hasClass("fdsa")).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

My expectation is that it wouldn't have the class until after 1000 milliseconds.  When I test this from the browser console, it behaves this way.

This is the sanity check that I used (tested in the Jasmine browser window).

```
el = $($("div")[0]);
el.addClass("qwer", 1000);
console.log(el.hasClass("qwer")); // output is "false"
setTimeout( function(){
  console.log(el.hasClass("qwer")); // output is "true"
}, 1001);
```

And this works always.  WTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the time to setup a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/ahus1/pZGdP/

I 'invented' what was necessary to get it working, like the `beforeEach`. I don't know the versions you used, but in this sample I used the latest ones available.

I noticed that it was only starting to work when I really added a proper class to the stylesheet. When there is no `.fdsa` class in the CSS, there's no transition, and the test will fail.

Maybe the fiddle will solve it for you. Please have a look.

Best regards,
Alexander.